# Trying to sort pairs but failing horribly(tideman/cs50)

Tags: c, cs50

look at my code and tell me what am I doing wrong cuz compiler is not  behaving much friendly .

```
void sort_pairs(void)
{for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < pair_count; j++)
        {
            const int temp = pairs[i][j];
            const int sudo = pairs[j][i];
            if pairs[i][j] > pairs[j][i]
            {
                pairs[j][i] = temp;
                pairs[i][j] = sudo;
            }
            return;
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: You most likely do not want to return inside the loop after the first iteration.

Comment: It is unlikely that the comparisons and swaps you want to perform are between `pairs[i][j]` and `pairs[j][i]`.  What you actually do want is unclear from your description and code, but for instance, if you want to sort by the first elements of the pairs, then the comparison would probably be more like `pairs[i][0] > pairs[j][0]`.  The swap, when it is performed, probably needs to swap both elements of one pair with both elements of the other.

Comment: We need to see the definition of your `pairs` array

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In C you need to use parentheses in condition:

```
if (pairs[i][j] > pairs[j][i])
{
    pairs[j][i] = temp;
    pairs[i][j] = sudo;
}
```

And this is all about only compiler problem.